# How to add elements in between an 1D Torch tensor?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, tensor

I have an 1D Torch tensor with dimension of ([384]). I want to put zeros or other numbers after each odd index of this tensor and eventually double its dimension to ([768]).
To be more specific, consider `[0, 1, 2,..., 382, 383]` as indices of my Torch tensor. assuming * is the index of zero/number I want to insert and make a tensor like `[0, 1, *, 2, 3, *,...]`.

The only solution I have is inserting these elements within a for loop but It would be time consuming. since I have to make these changes for hundreds of tensors, I wonder if PyTorch or NumPy has a faster function for this operation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any direct method of doing what you are asking for. I suppose that the following code (using torch.tensor indexing) is more sophisticated than what you are looking for, but just in case it helps you, I leave it here anyway.

```
import torch
import numpy as np

# Original tensor
your_1D_tensor_length = 6
original_tensor = torch.tensor(range(your_1D_tensor_length))

new_tensor = torch.zeros(size=(int(np.floor(original_tensor.shape[0]*(3/2))),))
new_tensor[0::3] = original_tensor[0::2]
new_tensor[1::3] = original_tensor[1::2]

print(original_tensor)
print(new_tensor)
```

Output:

```
tensor([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
tensor([0., 1., 0., 2., 3., 0., 4., 5., 0.])
```

Comment: thank you very much. it also works. I suggest you to take a look at the other answer too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a concatenation trick similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61026393/pytorch-concatenate-rows-in-alternate-order). Let's let `A` be a tensor of length `a` (in your case `a =384`). Let's say you want to add a new element every `n` elements (in your case `n = 2`). First, we reshape the list into a 2D array with `n` columns:
A = torch.rand(384)            # for example

```
a = A.shape[0]                 # 384
n = 2
insert_value = 10              # for example
A.shape                        #  shape is [384]


A = A.reshape(n-1,-1)          # shape is [192,2]
new = np.zeros([A.shape[0],1]) # shape is [192,1]
new += insert_value            # shape is [192,1]
B = torch.cat((A,new),dim = 1) # shape is [192,3]
```

And here's the only logically non-trivial bit. If we view or reshape  `B` as a one-dimensional tensor / list, pytorch ravels along the 0th dimension first, then the 1st dimension, and so on. That means for a 3D array, we'd end up with a list of rows of columns, and for a 2D array (as we have) we'll end up with a list of rows. This gives us the desired order.

```
result = B.reshape(-1) # shape is [576]

print(result)

>>> [rand,rand,10,rand,rand,10,rand,rand,10,...]
```

If you want to add more than one element between the existing elements of `A`, you can change the shape of `new` to be `[a,num_elem]` where `num_elem` is the number of elements you'd like to insert.